# Set the line separation in a tabu table equal to the line separation in the document

Tags: tables, line-spacing, tabu

As is known, the `tabu` environment does not automatically adjust the vertical distance between a cell with multiple lines and another cell, cf. [Text too close to cell border when having a nested tabu and \vspace in a cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82573/text-too-close-to-cell-border-when-having-a-nested-tabu-and-vspace-in-a-cell) and [Consistent vertical spacing with tabu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64337/consistent-vertical-spacing-with-tabu).

This can be adjusted with `tabu`'s `\tabulinesep` command, but instead of setting this separator to some arbitrary value, I would like it to be the same as the vertical distance between lines in the document as such. How do I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu,setspace}
    \singlespacing
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
%   \tabulinesep = <whatever the distance between lines in the document is>
    \begin{tabu} to\linewidth{lX}
        Lipsum & Fgyjgh Fgyjgh Fgyjgh Fgyjgh Fgyjgh Fgyjgh Fgyjgh Fgyjgh Fgyjgh Fgyjgh Fgyjgh\\
        Lipsum & FkRtfh\\
    \end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does @egreg's answer to [Strange line spacing effects in longtabu](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21571/5049) help?

Comment: @cgnieder: I don't know, because I don't know what ``strut`` is. Is that always equal to the line spacing in the document?

Comment: A strut is an invisible vertical rule with a height of 70% of `\baselineskip` and a depth of 30% of `\baselineskip`. Have you tried out the solution in the linked answer?

Comment: After some testing and careful comparison, it seems like adding ``<{\strut}`` to the ``X`` column does the trick. It would've been nice to add something about the ``strut`` to ``\tabulinesep=``, but I only get error messages.

Comment: the problem is not the line sep but the missing depth in `tabu`'s cells (this is a bug in `tabu`, IMHO). Setting `\tabulinesep` won't help to get consistent line spacing.

Comment: To judge from the linked answer, the author of ``tabu`` was made aware of this back in 2011 ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7993/discussion-between-cgnieder-and-sverre)